# Sort content in a view by taxonomy term and use terms as headlines in drupal 8

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 8

Say I have a content type `books` and a taxonomy vocabolary `book categorys` i.e.

```
book categorys:
 - Novel
 - Short Story
```

Now, what I would like to display in a view is:

**Novel**

- Novel 1
- Novel 2

**Short Story**

- Short Story 1
- Short Story 2

I sure can make one block for each taxonomy term and filter by term, but I also create regulary new ones so that is not an good option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you need a **Taxonomy term** view with a **Content using field_xxx** relationship.

Here are the steps needed:

1. Create a new view with **Show: Taxonomy terms of type: Book category** (or whatever your vocabulary is called).
2. Under **Advanced** settings add a Relationship of type **Content using field_bookcategory**
3. Under **Fields**, Add a Content Title field to the view. A relationship to your field_bookcategory should be automatically selected at this point.
4. You now need to group your results by taxonomy term. Do this under under **Format: Settings** and set **Grouping field Nr. 1** to **Taxonomy term: Name**
5. Lastly, you'll want to hide the term name in the results, since you're already displaying it in the group heading. To do this set the **Taxonomy term: Name** field to **Exclude from display**